# Why won't my nav button or button text move to the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a website for a company of mine, and the idea is that my main page is going to have a giant image with a button in the center (horizontally and vertically) that says "More!" but the button will not center nor will the text inside of the button, Below I'll put my HTML code as well as my CSS code too.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Biostone Interactive | Main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header-image">
      <div id="header-button">
        <a href="#" id="header-button-text">More!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">

    </div>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Tahoma, Arial;
}

#header-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
}

#header-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-button-text {
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

(Note this code isn't complete because I deleted some of it to try and fix it)
Please help me and tell me what I did wrong! Thanks :D

Comment: in `#header-button-text` `line-height = 50px;` and `vertical-align : middle;`

Comment: Please note that asking "What did I do wrong" is not an actual question. Please mention what doesn't work, and what you would expect.

Comment: I did tell what was wrong with it in the first paragraph and was meaning by "What I did wrong!" was explain what I did wrong and not asking "What did I do wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

To center text within a container, use `text-align:center;` 
To center a container, use `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`

```
#header-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;
}

#header-button-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, it needs to be in the center of the div vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Vertical Alignment is complicated.  Use this guide.  Click "vertically" to begin, and answer the questions it asks: 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

change the header button css to:

```
#header-button {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

The margin values need to be half of the dimension attributes, so if you change width and height you have to update the margins.